# C# Failed to add reference to 'System.ComponentModel'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

C# project problem with connection to Mysql . I tried to install MySql.Data package from NuGet. And after downloading, I saw next error

```
Failed to add reference to 'System.ComponentModel'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.
```

I tried add next into csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Runtime"/>
```

But still getting that error, how can I fix it?

Comment: Update your NuGet package manager (Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> NuGet Package Manager -> Update). Once done uninstall the package and install again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Comment: Kinda important: what framework / TFM are you targeting? and: what build tools are you using?